# Using a bounded wildcard (? extends) with a list of Converters gives a type mismatch error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, bounded-wildcard

I have the following classes:

```
import com.google.common.base.Converter;

public class CustomConverter extends Converter<MyClass, String> {

    // Implemented overrides are here and working
}
```

and

```
public class BaseModule {
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass extends BaseModule {
}
```

I want to have the following `Map`:

```
Map<EnumIdentifier, Converter<? extends BaseModule, String>> moduleToConverter;
```

And then in my code, I'm trying to do the following:

```
import lombok.val;

// ...

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    moduleToConverter = new HashMap<>();
    moduleToConverter.put(EnumIdentifier.MyClass, new CustomConverter());

    List<BaseModule> itemsToConvert = new ArrayList<>();
    itemsToConvert.add(new MyClass());

    for (BaseModule item : itemsToConvert) {
        val converter = moduleToConverter.get(EnumIdentifier.MyClass);
        val convertedData = converter.convert(item); // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

This gives the following error in IntelliJ

> convert
>   (capture<? extends BaseModule>) in Converter cannot be applied to (BaseModule)

Is there a way to get this idea to work? And if not, why not?

Comment: I think you have to actually declare a class for `BaseModule` and not use a wildcard.  The problem is that it doesn't know what class `? extends BaseModule` actually is, so you can't put `BaseModule` into that map (from your list of `itemsToConvert`).  Generics aren't covariant, the class has to match.  The construction `? extends Class` is termed a "producer" it can produce classes of type `Class` but you cannot safely add types to it.

Comment: C.f. this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: You'd have to use `super` rather than `extends`, unless you're only ever going to pass literal null to the `convert` method.